# How do I finish computing the associated graded ring of the localized ring $k[x]_{(x)}$ at its maximal ideal $(x)_{(x)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, graded-rings

We have the filtration:
$$k[x]_{(x)} \supset (x)_{(x)} \supset (x^2)_{(x)} \supset (x^3)_{(x)} \supset \cdots $$
and so we have
$${\rm gr}_{(x)_{(x)}} k[x]_{(x)} = \frac{k[x]_{(x)}}{(x)_{(x)}} \oplus \frac{(x)_{(x)}}{(x^2)_{(x)}} \oplus \frac{(x^2)_{(x)}}{(x^3)_{(x)}} \oplus \cdots$$
which simplifies to
$${\rm gr}_{(x)_{(x)}} k[x]_{(x)} = \left(\frac{k[x]}{(x)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x)}} \oplus \left(\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}} \oplus \left(\frac{(x^2)}{(x^3)}\right)_{\frac{(x^2)}{(x^3)}} \oplus \cdots.$$

---

I know $\left(\frac{k[x]}{(x)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x)}}$ simplifies to just $k$.

**However, what does $\left(\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}}$ simplify to?**

**Am I even thinking about this the right way?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which simplifies to
> $${\rm gr}_{(x)_{(x)}} k[x]_{(x)} = \left(\frac{k[x]}{(x)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x)}} \oplus \left(\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}} \oplus \left(\frac{(x^2)}{(x^3)}\right)_{\frac{(x^2)}{(x^3)}} \oplus \cdots.$$

I'm not sure this is right, unless I'm misunderstanding some notation. What does it mean to localize with respect to $(x)/(x^2)$? Which ring is that meant to be a multiplicative subset or prime ideal of? What is true is that $(A/B)_\mathfrak{p} = A_\mathfrak{p}/B_\mathfrak{p}$, since localization is exact. So I think it would be more correct to say

> $${\rm gr}_{(x)_{(x)}} k[x]_{(x)} = \left(\frac{k[x]}{(x)}\right)_{(x)} \oplus \left(\frac{(x)}{(x^2)}\right)_{(x)} \oplus \left(\frac{(x^2)}{(x^3)}\right)_{(x)} \oplus \cdots.$$

Now, each $(x)^n/(x)^{n+1}$ is a $1$-dimensional $k$-vector space (spanned by $x^n$) where $x$ acts trivially – therefore, as a $k$-vector space, we have

$${\rm gr}_{(x)_{(x)}} k[x]_{(x)} \cong \bigoplus_\mathbb{N} k.$$

In order to really determine the associated graded *ring* though, we must also understand the multiplicative structure. So, to check your understanding: what is the product operation $(\bigoplus_\mathbb{N} k) \times (\bigoplus_\mathbb{N} k) \to \bigoplus_\mathbb{N} k$? And what well-known ring is ${\rm gr}_{(x)_{(x)}} k[x]_{(x)}$ isomorphic to?

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I was misunderstanding localization. However, in the first summand, would it be more correct to write $\left(\frac{k[x]}{(x)}\right)_{\frac{(x)}{(x)}}$?

Comment: I see why I was wrong in the other summands. But the first summand I believe is correct.

Comment: No, that would not be more correct. Remember, the original quotient is $k[x]_{(x)}/(x)_{(x)}$ – in particular, we are taking a quotient of $k[x]_{(x)}$-modules. When we transform this quotient of localization to a localization of the quotient, this is all happening at the level of modules, so the quotient should be thought of $(k[x]/(x))_{(x)}$; that is, the $(x)$-localization of the quotient of the $k[x]$-modules $k[x]$ and $(x)$. On the other hand, if you write $(k[x]/(x))_{(x)/(x)}$, you are talking about the localization of the quotient *ring* $k[x]/(x)$ at the prime ideal $(x)/(x)$. (1/2)

Comment: These two versions of the localization are isomorphic as $k[x]_{(x)}$-modules, so you *can* think about it either way, but I think it's more precise to think about it as $(k[x]/(x))_{(x)}$. The ring structure on the $0$th graded piece is indeed given by $(k[x]/(x))_{(x)/(x)}$, but that isn't very useful in this context, where we are going to describe the ring structure of the entire associated graded anyway. (2/2)

Comment: I'm coming back to this since I've run into it again. In your first paragraph, you write "What does it mean to localize with respect to $(x)/(x^2)$?"

Comment: We have that $(x)/(x^2)$ is a $k[x]/(x^2)$-module. So, aren't we localizing with respect to the ideal $(x)/(x^2) \subset k[x]/(x^2)$ ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?